# Android: Enviar dados via POST

Tags: java, android, json, post

Eu sei como fazer isto em outras linguagens de programação, entretanto, ao procurar por exemplos de como enviar dados usando `POST` no `Android`, so acho exemplos que utilizam classes descontinuadas, como:

- `HttpClient`
- `HttpPost`
- `HttpResponse`
- `HttpEntity`
- `EntityUtils`
- `NameValuePair`
- `BasicNameValuePair`

Estou buscando uma maneira de enviar um `json` via `POST` de um aplicativo `Android` e recuperá-los em uma aplicação com servlets. A parte das servlets não é um problema. Consigo recuperar um json e tratá-lo utilizando a lib [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) da Google.

Comment: Por exemplo, [depreciado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70230/android-como-enviar-dados-via-post-e-recuperar-em-um-php)

Comment: A palavra *"depreciado"* em português soa diferente, o melhor termo é *descontinuado*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza a biblioteca nativa do Android [Volley](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/volley/simple.html). [Aqui](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/) tem outro exemplo de como implementar.

```
final String url = "some/url";
final JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject("{\"type\":\"example\"}");

new JsonObjectRequest(url, jsonBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() { ... });
Here is the source code and JavaDoc (@param jsonRequest):

/** 
 * Creates a new request. 
 * @param method the HTTP method to use 
 * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from 
 * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONObject} to post with the request. Null is allowed and 
 *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request. 
 * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response 
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors. 
 */ 
public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
        Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
                errorListener);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o retrofit, leia sobre: [aqui](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Exemplo de uso:

**Crie uma interface:**

```
 public interface SUAINTERFACE {
     @POST("users/new")
     Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);//dados passados no corpo
    }
```

**Método para requisição:**

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/") //sua base_url
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

    SUAINTERFACE service = retrofit.create(SUAINTERFACE.class);
    Call<User> user = service.createUser(new User());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        Log.i("retorno",response.message().equals("OK") //sucesso 200
        //dados da resposta:
        response.body();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Mais sobre o retrofit você pode encontrar: [aqui](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en)